# Laravel : create two tables in one method

Tags: database, laravel-5, web

i have two tables (photos and services)
services has photo_id as forien key, i want to create photo and service which include photo_id at the same time.

this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $target_dir = public_path('uploading/');

    if($request->hasFile('img')){

        $imageFileType = strtolower($_FILES["img"]["type"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;

        $imageFileType = explode('/', $imageFileType)[1];

        $target_file_name = md5(date('YmdHis') . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]));

        $target_file = $target_dir . $target_file_name . '.' . $imageFileType;


        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]);



        if ($check != false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }


        if ($imageFileType != "svg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif") {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        $i = 0;

        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

                $photo = Photo::create(['photo' => $target_file_name. '.' . $imageFileType]);
                Service::create([
                    'title'=>$request->title,
                    'description'=>$request->description,
                    'photo_id'=>$photo->id]);

                echo "The file has been uploaded.";

            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

any thing below
 $photo = Photo::create(); not executed, and i don't know why.

i try dd($photo), echo $photo but it returns me nothing.

when i put service::create() outside the if(), it return $photo undefiend

any one could see anything wrong with my code, it will be so helpful.

Comment: Any sample code that you might want to include related to your question

Comment: i update the question

Answer (score 0):

as what I understood , you want to separate the image processing to a separate function in your controller, you can easily define a private method in your controller and call it from your store method like this , `$this->cropAndSaveImage($requestData)` , note you can pass the request data as the parameter to get the image details,

or second way you can save the image upload,crop via a ajax call to a specific controller method directly and form submission to another controller method.

Just sharing your one of my blog posts which might be helpful for you.
https://www.techalyst.com/links/read/72/facebook-like-profile-photo-upload-in-laravel-5-using-jquery-croppic-plugin

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $target_file_name = $this->cropAndSaveImage($request);
    $title = $request->title;
    $description = $request->description;
    Service::create(['title'=>$title,'description'=>$description,'image'=>$target_file_name . '.' . $imageFileType]);



}


private function cropAndSaveImage(Request $request)
{
     $target_dir = public_path('uploading/');
     $target_file_name = '';
    if($image = $request->hasFile('img')) {


        $imageFileType = strtolower($_FILES["img"]["type"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;


        $imageFileType = explode('/', $imageFileType)[1];


        $target_file_name = md5(date('YmdHis') . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]));



        $target_file = $target_dir . $target_file_name . '.' . $imageFileType;



        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]);



        if ($check != false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }


        if ($imageFileType != "svg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif") {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }


        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        } else {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);


        }

        return $target_file_name;


    }
}
```

Comment: i did this $this->cropAndSaveImage($requestData) ,but how to get this $requestData in the store method?

Comment: sorry, but it returns null:(